# produce text from xml python

Tags: xml, python-3.x

using python3.4, I am trying to extract all text from xml file. I used:

```
tree = etree.parse(xmlFile)
notags = etree.tostring(tree, encoding='utf8', method='text')
```

This removed all the xml tags and give me just the text. but I have 3 problems with the result:

1. `“almost square”` turned to `\xe2\x80\x9calmost square\xe2\x80\x9d`
2. `<title><tag close=" ">1</tag>Introduction</title>`
   turned into `1Introduction`
   while I need a space between 1 and Introduction
3. the reference like:  `In [<ref labelref="LABEL:C"/>]`
   turned into `In []`

Is there better way of having the text without the tags without this problems?

Thanks

Comment: In other words, you want to have spaces for some tags, but not for others, and want the values of some attributes to end up in the text, but not of others? I don't think there's a generic solution for this. What kind of XML is this? What schema?

Comment: I can understand 2 and 3. but in 1 why the quotation marks changed?

Answer (score 0):

1. Quotation-marks are changed because you pass `encoding='utf8'` and it returns byte string.
   Here what help on `tostring` says:

> You can also serialise to a Unicode string without declaration by
>       passing the `unicode` function as encoding (or `str` in Py3),
>       or the name 'unicode'.  This changes the return value from a byte
>       string to an unencoded unicode string.

Use `encoding='unicode'` if you want unicode string

2. I think in this case you will have to iterate over a tree manually.
3. Sure. What did you expect?

Comment: changing to encoding='unicode' gives this error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2009' in position 1193: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Can't say what's wrong without seeing an xml-file, but you can also try `etree.tostring(tree, encoding='utf8', method='text').decode()`.